# Understanding socket.io's documentation pattern

Tags: javascript, socket.io

In socket.io's [server documentation](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#), there is a syntax that is repeatedly used that I'm not familiar with.

For example: `Server#origins(v:String):Server`

1. What is the `#` referring to? Is it the start of the method?
2. What is the `:Server` at the end referring to?

This pattern of `Server#...:Server` is repeatedly used, so I'm assuming it's something fundamental.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448921/what-is-this-javascript-documentation-style-called

Comment: Indeed, although there aren't any answers posted for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the exact syntax comes from as it isn't javascript, but pieces of it look familiar from other languages.

By deduction, it works like this:

```
class#method(arg:argtype):returnValue
```

So, in your example:

```
Server#origins(v:String):Server
```

`Server` is the object type.

`origins` is the method name

`v` is the first argument to that method

`String` is the type of the first argument

`Server` is the type of the return value from the method